# How to read a file content uploaded through mongodb (gridfs) in api at server side in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, gridfs

Hello All,
I upload a (.json) file to mongodb (gridfs) and I want to read the content of that file in my api at server side in meteor. Is it possible to do so ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Hi CodeChimp, Do you have any demo code for this or any suggestion ?

Comment: You have full access to the MongoDB on the server side, so it would work the same way there that it does client-side.  In fact, on the server-side you actually have **more** access to MongoDB since the client is really connecting to minimongo and synced through the pub/sub process.